# How can I stop Netbeans from login into a Subversion server?

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

I rent a VPS and I installed a Subversion server on it.
When I went to test, I exported a project to my subversion server, I dont remember exactly what I did. All I know is that the Project that is in my svn is ok, but all others are marked with 'New Locally'.
Is there anything I can make for my Netbeans to stop saying new locally since I dont want to use svn with those projects.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Options > Miscellaneous > Versioning`. *Locally New* suggests a Mercurial artifact if you perhaps chose either of these:

- `Versioning > Initialize Mercurial Repository` from the project's right-click menu.
- `Team > Mercurial > Initialize Repository` from the IDE's main menu.